# Source Not Available while debug - Visual Studio 2017 (probably heap memory)

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-2017, heap-memory

I'm pretty new in programming and I'm working on assignment to my college.
In that assignment there is a need to allocate a lot of memory allocations and it may cause my problem. When I debug the program I got this exception:
[image: heap exception]

[image: Source Not Available]

Best regards.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to step into a Microsoft library or kernel routine for which the source is not supplied.  Use "step-over" when you come to library routines like `malloc()`.

Comment: I got this exception when I use "step-over", when I'm not using it the program just twit an exception sound and exit immediately.

Comment: Since the exception is thrown inside Microsoft Libraries, to "step-over", you need to have those symbol files.. check this link..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server

Comment: Look back through the call stack to see the line of your code which triggered the exception.  "Source Not Available" is not the exception you are looking for.

Comment: @Oran Sherf, One possible reason is that you really has no source code for the dll you want to debug. If you really want to debug your app and capture the Exception, just use the Exception settings window in your side.